# JsonStatus - A tiny C++ JSON writer

Tags: c++, json

## JsonStatus

(as in status file)

### Goal

A simple and fast JSON writer in C++ (JSON output only). When you need something so small that you're not sure you even *need* a JSON library and you don't feel like adding lots of code into your project but you also want something to take care of the commas, colons and braces for you.

### Properties

Minimum verification and assumes that data is added in-order.

Doesn't protect against duplicate keys and values can't be modified, only written once.

Writes directly to a file.

### Code

#### Usage example

```
    JsonStatus jst;
    jst.setFileName("aaa.json");
    jst.initArray();
    jst.pushVal(1);
    jst.pushVal(2);
    jst.objectInArray();
    jst.pushKeyArray("arr");
    jst.pushVal(3);
    jst.pushVal(4);
    jst.close();  // pops all nested

    //Output: [1, 2, {"arr" : [3, 4]}]

    jst.setFileName("bbb.json");
    jst.initObject();
    jst.pushKeyArray("arr");
    jst.pushVal(1);
    jst.pushVal(2);
    jst.popNested(); // End arr
    jst.pushKeyVal("keyA", 3);
    jst.pushKeyObject("othertypes");
    jst.pushKeyVal("keyB", 4.001);
    jst.pushKeyObject("strings");
    jst.pushKeyVal("keyC", "5");
    jst.pushKeyVal("keyD", std::string("5") + "+1");
    jst.popNested(); // End strings
    jst.pushKeyVal("keyE", 'E');
    jst.close();  // pops all nested

    //Output: {"arr" : [1, 2], "keyA" : 3, "othertypes" : {"keyB" : 4.001, "strings" : {"keyC" : "5", "keyD" : "5+1"}, "keyE" : "E"}}
```

#### Header file

```
#ifndef JSONSTATUS_H_
#define JSONSTATUS_H_

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>

class JsonStatus
{
public:
    void setFileName(const std::string& fileName);
    void initObject();
    void initArray();
    void close();

    void pushKeyVal(const std::string& key, const std::string& val);
    void pushKeyVal(const std::string& key, const char* val);
    void pushKeyVal(const std::string& key, char val);

    template <class T>
    void pushKeyVal(const std::string& key, const T& val)
    {
        pushKey(key);
        jsonString << val;
    }

    // adding elements to a JSON array
    void pushVal(const std::string& val);
    void pushVal(const char* val);
    void pushVal(char val);

    template <class T>
    void pushVal(const T& val)
    {
        arrayState();
        jsonString << val;
    }

    // Nested arrays and objects
    void objectInArray();
    void pushKeyArray(const std::string&);
    void pushKeyObject(const std::string&);
    void popNested();
    void popAllNested();

private:
    void pushKey(const std::string& key);
    void arrayState();
    void writeStringInQuotes(const char* str);
    void writeCharInQuotes(char c);

    enum class Nested
    {
        Object,
        Array
    };

    std::string fileName;
    std::ofstream jsonString;
    struct level
    {
        Nested nested;
        int count = 0;
    };

    std::stack<level> currentLevel;
};

#endif /* JSONSTATUS_H_ */
```

#### Implementation file

```
#include "JsonStatus.h"

void JsonStatus::setFileName(const std::string& fileNameArg)
{
    fileName = fileNameArg;
}

void JsonStatus::pushKeyVal(const std::string &key, const std::string &val)
{
    pushKeyVal(key, val.c_str());
}

void JsonStatus::pushKeyVal(const std::string &key, const char *val)
{
    pushKey(key);
    writeStringInQuotes(val);
}

void JsonStatus::pushKeyVal(const std::string& key, char val)
{
    pushKey(key);
    writeCharInQuotes(val);
}

void JsonStatus::pushVal(const std::string& val)
{
    pushVal(val.c_str());
}

void JsonStatus::pushVal(const char* val)
{
    arrayState();
    writeStringInQuotes(val);
}

void JsonStatus::pushVal(char val)
{
    arrayState();
    writeCharInQuotes(val);
}

void JsonStatus::objectInArray()
{
    arrayState();
    jsonString << '{';
    currentLevel.push(level{ Nested::Object });
}

void JsonStatus::pushKey(const std::string &key)
{
    if (currentLevel.empty())
        throw std::runtime_error("JsonStatus was not initialized");
    if (currentLevel.top().nested != Nested::Object)
        throw std::runtime_error("Pushed a key to an array");
    if (currentLevel.top().count)
        jsonString << ", ";
    writeStringInQuotes(key.c_str());
    jsonString << " : ";
    ++currentLevel.top().count;
}

void JsonStatus::arrayState()
{
    if (currentLevel.empty())
        throw std::runtime_error("JsonStatus was not initialized");
    if (currentLevel.top().nested != Nested::Array)
        throw std::runtime_error("Pushed a value without key to an object");
    if (currentLevel.top().count)
        jsonString << ", ";
    ++currentLevel.top().count;
}


void JsonStatus::pushKeyArray(const std::string &key)
{
    pushKey(key);
    jsonString << '[';
    currentLevel.push(level{ Nested::Array });
}

void JsonStatus::pushKeyObject(const std::string &key)
{
    pushKey(key);
    jsonString << '{';
    currentLevel.push(level{ Nested::Object });
}

void JsonStatus::popNested()
{
    if (currentLevel.empty())
        throw std::runtime_error("JsonStatus was not initialized");
    if (currentLevel.top().nested == Nested::Array)
        jsonString << ']';
    else if (currentLevel.top().nested == Nested::Object)
        jsonString << '}';
    currentLevel.pop();
}

void JsonStatus::initObject()
{
    jsonString.open(fileName);
    if (jsonString.is_open() == false || jsonString.good() == false)
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open JSON path for writing");

    while (!currentLevel.empty())
        currentLevel.pop();

    jsonString << '{';
    currentLevel.push(level{ Nested::Object });
}

void JsonStatus::initArray()
{
    jsonString.open(fileName);
    if (jsonString.is_open() == false || jsonString.good() == false)
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open JSON path for writing");

    while (!currentLevel.empty())
        currentLevel.pop();

    jsonString << '[';
    currentLevel.push(level{ Nested::Array });
}

void JsonStatus::popAllNested()
{
    while (!currentLevel.empty())
        popNested();
}

void JsonStatus::close()
{
    popAllNested();
    jsonString.close();
}

void JsonStatus::writeStringInQuotes(const char* str)
{
    // if you're feeling fancy, escape special characters, not doing it for now.
    jsonString << '"';
    jsonString << str;
    jsonString << '"';
}

void JsonStatus::writeCharInQuotes(char c)
{
    char str[] = { c,'\0' };
    writeStringInQuotes(str);
}
```